# approximating the sum of an alternating series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation

I needed to prove that the series $$\dfrac{(-1)^{(n+1)}\ln(n)}{n}$$
starting from $n=2$, converges  and then find the approximation of the sum of the series. I managed to prove the convergence using the Leibniz alternating series test.
But now I'm kind of stuck with the next question, how do i find the approximation of the sum?

I do know that the sum resides in   $a_2< S <0$ using the Leibniz alternating series test. But is that considered an approximation?

Comment: I imagine they just want you to calculate a few terms and state an error which you find reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent approximation to the sum of the series as $n\to\infty$ is
$$
\frac12 (\ln 2)^2 - \gamma \approx -0.1599
$$ 
where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant $$
\gamma = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k -\ln(n)\right)$$

Possibly your problem poser meant to ask for a good asymptotic form for the value of the $n$-th sum in the series, that is, an approximation, in terms of $n$, of 
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=2}^n (-1)^{1+k}\frac{\ln(k)}{k}
$$
That is quite a meaty problem, but might be doable without very advanced techniques.

Comment: do you think it will qualify if i just take the first value and then add the remainder( which i can describe using k) because the remainder describes the margin of error  so it basically gives the approximation using n off any value from n=2.